# Add OpenTelemetry to a .Net Framework 4.6 Console Application

Tags: .net, console-application, .net-4.6, open-telemetry

I am trying to add Open Telemetry logging to a .NET Framework 4.6 console application.
I have found many examples for .net core but not .NET Framework 4.6
Are there any examples ?